# DD4T Java, ways to render Component Presentations?

Tags: dd4t

In an older post from 2012, Albert Romkes explained [ways to render Component Presentations with DD4T for .NET](http://albertromkes.com/2012/01/20/dd4t-continued-rendering-component-presentations/) , namely with HTML helpers. For example:

- `@Html.RenderComponentPresentations()`
- `@Html.RenderComponentPresentationsBySchema("ArticleSchema")`
- `@Html.RenderComponentPresentationsByView("Article")`
- `@Html.RenderComponentPresentationsByView(new[] {"Article", "FullArticle" })`

Does DD4T for Java have similar functionality?

Background: I'm updating a content model which renders all Component Presentations in the "main content area" of the page. But I now have webpage metadata (seo fields) and other content to place in specific parts of the page (like [partitioning CPs](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/PartitionComponentPresentations), but with Java DD4T).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but its different. In the dd4t-example-site, the connection between pageviews and componentviews isn't direct as in dotnet, but looped through the controller and the componentviews model. In dotnet, the pageview would use these helpers to render componentviews. In java, the controller pre-renders the componentviews (check the contentcontroller and the jspcomponenentviewhandler - they implement the rendering calls) and then passes on the bunch of rendered component html snippets to the page view.

If you want to do the "dotnet style" way, all you have to do is write an accessor class where the page view can call the jspcomponentviewhandler.

Comment: So this accessor class could include parameters for the Schemas and/or Component Templates similar to the *dotnet style*? The devs would then call this class to get the component views (e.g. functionally only CPs with Schema Banner go here).

Comment: Yes exactly. The component presentations you're looking for are already available in the request, they're inside of the pagemodel. All you need to do is define how you'd like to render them (by schema, region, view, etc) and code the selection from the list. Once selected, you pass the component(presentation) to the componentviewhandler to render it into html and return it as a string.

Comment: Okay, in the dd4t-example-site, I found the [ContentController](https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/blob/master/java/dd4t-example-site/src/org/dd4t/springmvc/controller/ContentController.java) and [JSPComponentViewHandler](https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/blob/29bfc01643093398fe3404db56bf0219919697df/java/dd4t-example-site/src/org/dd4t/springmvc/view/impl/JSPComponentViewHandler.java). @Rogier, is there an example accessor I can show the team (or what would its signature look like)? We're a little stuck on "you know, get me the CPs by this template." :-)

Comment: *Update*: the team found `<dd4t:componentpresentations  view="view_name"/>` which renders only Component Presentations that match a given view. There are also attributes for `region`, `rootElement`, and `schema`. We might have been on an earlier DD4T build and/or someone added this functionality.

Comment: Sorry, don't have any real example code because i prefer to use the pre-rendered method (using the content controller to build the componentviews model, and then having the page view use the componentviews). There may be usable code for you in dd4t-2 though, which is probably where your team found that.

Comment: Ok, I see the same preference here. To be sure, does that work best with "flat" HTML where the CPs are siblings to each other? Or do you need containers to make a "plain" componentpresentations tag work? I can start a separate question if this if off-topic.